# How do i toggle <li> sortable status when it is an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a 3x3 puzzle game. Eventually I would like to build it so that individual pieces can be locked into their position on the list when they are double clicked. Right now, though, I'm focused on building a function that will change the `class` status when the piece is `dblclick`

Here is my code for that:

```
<body>

<div id="puzzleboard">
    <ul id="pieces">

        <li></li><li ></li><li></li><li ></li><li ></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>

    </ul>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = populate;

    var imgArray = new Array("images/Untitled-0.png","images/Untitled-1.png","images/Untitled-2.png","images/Untitled-3.png","images/Untitled-4.png","images/Untitled-5.png","images/Untitled-6.png","images/Untitled-7.png","images/Untitled-8.png");

    var usedImg = new Array()

    var itemArray = new Array ("item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8")

    var div = document.getElementById("pieces");

    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

    function populate(){



        for (i=0; i<list.length;i++){

                var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);//generates a random #

                var img = new Image(); // creates a new image object
                img.src = imgArray[randomNum]; //source of the image is based on the random # and correlating item in imgArray

                do {
                    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);
                    img.src = imgArray[randomNum]; //generates a new number
                } while (usedImg[img.src]); // but only if the source of the image is in used images


                usedImg[img.src] = true; //copies img.src to used image

                var imgPlace=document.createElement('img'); //instruct it to create an img tag
                imgPlace.src=img.src; //defines source

                var item = list[i]

                list[i].id = itemArray[randomNum];


                list[i].appendChild(imgPlace);

        };

    };


    $(list).dblclick(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-disabled');
        });

     $( function() {
        $( "#pieces" ).sortable({
          items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"

        });

     });

</script>
```

This works fine with script, but I have an `<img>` in each `<li>`. The page will load all `<li>` with `class="ui-sortable-handle"`, and when a piece is `dblclick` it becomes `class="ui-sortable-handle ui-state-disabled"`, the image  but when I `dblclick` on that piece again, it does not change back. So How do i toggle `<li>` sortable status when it is an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
$( function() {
        $("#pieces").sortable({
          items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"

        });
        $("#pieces li").dblclick(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-disabled');
            //$(this).children().toggleClass('ui-state-disabled'); //if you want to change property of the image for example opacity
        });     


     });
```

But it is the same that your code, please check if you don't have a JavaScript error in other script of your page, with the console of the browser (normally with F12 key)

Comment: so if I use $(this).children().toggleClass('ui-state-disabled'); it works. Still confused why the other isn't work (no script errors), but yeah. Thanks!